# How to redirect index.php/controller/action to controller/action without redirect loop?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Solved :)**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index.php
RewriteRule index.php(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

---

I configured a redirect so that I can open http://example.com/controller/action and ModRewrite route the request internal to ...index.php/controller/action.

Now I want to redirect a user if he opened http://example.com/index.php/controller/action automaticly to index.php/controller/action (301 redirect). But now I get an endless loop of redirects.

Is there any chance to seperate the internal redirect to the bootstrap index.php and prevent, that one user can open the url with the index.php subpath?

I tried this, but that doesnt work (enless loop):

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php/(.*)
 RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You shouldnt really need to rewrite with that first condition/rule... because both urls **should** do exactly the same thing. If they dont youve got a bad implementation ;-)

Comment: The first rule make an external redirect (301) the second an internal. So it's not the same ;).

When a user open the url with index.php then he should redirect to the version without index.php. But the version without index.php must be internal redirected to the bootstrap file index.php and thats the conflict.

Comment: Opps... you are correct... totally missed that. However if youre using the same shceme just redirecting the url as-is to the new host should do the same thing. i mean effectively `/index.php/controller/action` is the same as `/controller/action` as far as your router should be concerned. Normally your last rule would look like: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]` not the lack of the capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Common way to solve this on PHP side is to have counter which increments with every redirect. E.g.: https://github.com/vjousse/symfony-1.4/blob/master/lib/controller/sfController.class.php

```
if ($this->getActionStack()->getSize() >= $this->maxForwards)
{
  // let's kill this party before it turns into cpu cycle hell
  throw new sfForwardException('Too many forwards have been detected for this request.');
}
```

Comment: But I don't search for a solution to stop the loop - I want to make a difference to prevent the loop by differentiate between internal and external routing in the rewrite condition :)